# error while attempting to concet in tfs TF400898

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

[image]
the following error appears when trying to access my project that is in TFS, what can cause this?

error:

```
{
  "$id": "1",
  "innerException": null,
  "message": "TF400898: An Internal Error Occurred.",
  "typeName": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.CircuitBreaker.CircuitBreakerShortCircuitException, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common",
  "typeKey": "CircuitBreakerShortCircuitException",
  "errorCode": 0,
  "eventId": 3000
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for this inconvenience. This is caused by our Azure DevOps event. And we are urgently fixing this problem.

You can **keep track of** this issue in this URL：**https://status.dev.azure.com/_event/125087577** .If any progress, we will update this event log.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same problem.  Microsoft is aware and working on a solution.  Check the status here: https://status.dev.azure.com/_event/125087577

Comment: That status only reports Brazil and U.S. as having issues, however others are reporting many other regions (Canada, Europe, Argentina, India, Germany) in a ticket which points to that status (in a Microsoft reply) as well -- https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/596070/tf400898-an-internal-error-occurred-12.html